# UNION ALL and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select all data from two different tables, grouping identical data of the fields of the 2 tables. The query groups the data of the tables, but does not group them all together:

```
SELECT product,
product_modified,
amount,
SUM(quantity) AS q FROM bills_stored
GROUP BY product

UNION ALL

SELECT product,
product_modified,
product_amount,
SUM(quantity) AS q FROM ordering
GROUP BY product ORDER BY q DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first take the union, and then aggregate:

```
SELECT
    product,
    SUM(quantity) AS q
FROM
(
    SELECT product, quantity FROM bills_stored
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product, quantity FROM ordering
) t
GROUP BY product;
```

Note that if you also want to select the `product_modified` column then rightfully it should also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: This only works when the union is combining results from the same table not different tables.

Answer (score -2):

SQLite will not aggregate results from a union on two different tables. Only on unions of the same table can you aggregate the results by wrapping the union in a select. The correct way to do this is to dump the results of a union into a temp table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.aggregation;
CREATE TEMP TABLE aggregation AS
    SELECT product, quantity FROM bills_stored
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product, quantity FROM ordering
```

Now you can query and aggregate the results.

```
SELECT
    product,
    SUM(quantity) AS q
FROM
(
    temp.aggregation
) t
GROUP BY product;
```

Then drop the temp table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.aggregation
```